# File upload: How to check if any file is selected using Multipart file-upload

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a web api to upload file using Multipart file-upload following the instructions here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2 .
I wounder if there is any way to check if any file is selected or not. Yes the length can be checked if it is zero but what if an empty file was actually uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` useful to check. Because a file should have a name.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in web api.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You have already mentioned the length property, you can also check  the expected file extension, e.g., .jpeg, jpg, .png, .gif, .swf, .pdf, .doc, .docx etc.

When the user uploads the file, get the file path

```
public string GetFileExtension(){
   string fileName = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
   string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
   return extension;
}
```

//Validate

```
    public bool IsValidFileExtension(string fileExtension)
    {
       switch(fileExtension)
       {
         case ".jpeg":
            return true; 
            break;

           case ".jpeg":
            return true; 
            break;
          default:
            return false;
       }

      return false;
   }
```

//Validate

```
string fileExtension = GetFileExtension(fileExtension);
bool IsValidFile = IsValidFileExtension(fileExtension);
```

Comment: As I said length is not good criteria as the file may be a zero-length one. Moreover, the extension is open.

Comment: I mentioned check both length and the file extension. What you do is validate the file extension

Comment: Yes I got you. I meant file extension + length is not bullet proof.

Comment: Best is valid against properties you expect your file to have. Length, Size, Filename, file extension, I say best because nothing is bullet proof on the internet. Imagine you expect a user to enter a first name "John" in a first name field on your web site and they enter "Blah Blah", it is not a first name for anyone, the moral is , you cannot check every first name in the world but we valid for empty string, length etc. You get the idea